# lsphp states: no space left on device but there is enough free space available on the server

Tags: linux, debian, php

I got a debian server installed with openlitespeed and wordpress.

I regularly get a 503 error; when I check the logs I see the following:

```
ERROR   [lsphp]: Failed to listen socket [/tmp/lshttpd/lsphp.sock]: No space left on device
WARN    [uds://tmp/lshttpd/lsphp.sock] Can not start this external application.
```

However, there is plenty of space left when I check:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  628K  394M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        78G  6.7G   71G   9% /
tmpfs           2.0G  1.2M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0      1.5G   25M  1.3G   2% /tmp
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas to check, in random order:

- Typically, on a "native" filesystem on a Linux-based OS, certain amount of free space is reserved for super user (`root`).
  On Debian (and "Debianoids" such as Ubuntu) the installer usually reserves 5% of free space on each device for this. Back in the day of 1 GiB that was sensible, but these days this means quite plenty of space.

  You might change this using dedicated tools such as `tune2fs` for `extN` filesystems.
  `tune2fs` accepts the `-r reserved_blocks_count` option, so to reserve, say, 100 MiB for root, you do `dumpe2fs -h | grep ^Block\ size` to know the block size (usually 4096), then do `echo $((100*1024*1024/4096))` and use the resulting blocks count in the call.

  Note that you might be tempted to set this count to 0 but it's unwise to do so: the reservation is there for a reason: it provides some wiggle room for the admin to move stuff or temporarily save stuff when dealing with the system with no free space left.
- Some Linux filesystems support per-user quotas.
  You might be hitting exactly this case.
- You might be facing "natural" fluctuation of free disk space.

  For instance, log rotation is typically set to run once a day.
  So, running programs might log stuff several hours in a row — naturally growing their logs and reducing the free space.
  Then log rotation happens, logs are compressed, old logs removed, and the free space is back to normal.
  Then the cycle repeats.
  Sometimes more stuff gets logged than usually, and the free space drops to zero.

  Other natural causes might exist.
  For instance, to handle a typical file upload the web server usually creates a temporary file on a filesystem and then streams the bytes from the client to that file; after the client is done, the file is rewound to the beginning and parsed.
  If you have many clients doing such uploads, free space might get eaten up.
  If, for whatever reason, the server software is so badly written that it lefts such a temporary file linger when the request is terminated prematurely, such files might pile up.
  If there exists some reaper script running periodically, this might explain why there are p    eriods of no free space and periods when it's back to normal.

As you could guess, any such activity (something piles up and then gets cleaned up) might account for the observed behaviour.

As to what to do about it…
If you won't be able to find some "obvious" cause, a continuously running accounting tool such as the venerable [`atop`](https://www.atoptool.nl/) might come int handy; it's usually packaged for any sensible Linux-based OS.
Basically it runs a daemon which periodically dumps a set of stats about the system parameters and then allows the administrator to inspect how the system behaved based on those logs.